# Rolling 2 dice 1000 times and counting the number of times the sum of the two dice hit

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, dice

The homework is requiring us to find out the probabilities of 2 to 12 as the sum by experiment. We want to roll two dices 1000 times and count the number of times the sum is 2, 3, …, and 12. I have this as my code so far, but im unable to get the output that the professor is asking for. 
[image: output of ex. code]

What I have so far:

```
import random as r

die_1 = r.randint(1,6)
die_2 = r.randint(1,6)


print('For-Loop')
for i in range(2,13):
    r.seed(1)
    counter = 0
    for j in range(1000):
        if i == r.randint(2,12):
            counter = counter + 1
    print("sum = ", i,  " count = ",  counter)
```

Comment: You roll your dice `11 * 1000` times. It's no big deal, but your description says differently.

Comment: @finefoot does not mean link to the image - he/she means paste the code into the body of the question *please*.

Comment: You don’t say what she is looking for, but probabilities are in the range 0 to 1, so maybe just divide your values by the total of all your values

Comment: _but im unable to get the output that the professor is asking for._ What does that mean?

Comment: @AMC I added a picture of what the example output looks like

Comment: What's wrong with your current code?

Answer (score 4):

```
from random import randint

rolls = [sum([randint(1, 6), randint(1, 6)]) for i in range(1000)]

for i in range(2, 13):
    print(f'Sum of {i} was rolled {rolls.count(i)} times')
```

Comment: Binomial theorem

Answer (score 4):

I have tried to explain everything that's happening in the comments:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
from random import randint

# Roll the two dice how many times?
n = 1000

# Create a dictionary to store the results
results = defaultdict(int)

# Loop n times
for _ in range(n):
    # Get random numbers for the two dice
    die_1 = randint(1, 6)
    die_2 = randint(1, 6)
    # Increase the corresponding result by 1
    results[die_1 + die_2] += 1

# Print results
print(results)
```

Which might print something like this:

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {7: 160, 8: 134, 6: 145, 9: 107, 3: 50, 10: 76, 12: 26, 4: 86, 5: 128, 2: 37, 11: 51})
```

You can also easily illustrate the results with a plot:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.bar(results.keys(), results.values())
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: if you are wondering why the plot looks like this OP, the convolution of two nice distributions is *nice* and `N(\mu, \sigma)` is the *nicest of them all* - even discretely ;)

Answer (score 3):

You are not correctly accounting for the probabilities. `r.randint(2, 12)` is not the same as independently rolling two die (as their are multiple rolls of two that sum to the same value, for some values).

```
import collections
import random

print("For Loop")

occurrences = []
for trial in range(1000):
    die1 = random.randint(1, 6)
    die2 = random.randing(1, 6)
    occurrences.append(die1 + die2)
counter = collections.Counter(occurrences)
for roll, count in counter.items():
    print(f"sum = {roll} count = {count}")
```

if you do not want to import other parts of the standard library you can make the counter yourself.

```
import random

print("For Loop")
occurrences = {}
for trial in range(1000):
    die1 = random.randint(1, 6)
    die2 = random.randing(1, 6)
    roll = die1 + die2
    current = occurrences.setdefault(roll, 0)
    occurrences[roll] = current + 1

for roll, count in occurrences.items():
    print(f"sum = {roll} count = {count}")
```

note that the outputs will be slightly different as their is, of course, randomness involved.